# MySQL Error: 1395 Can not delete from join view

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete a record from a view which was generated by join of multiple tables. I have a new user to delete and insert on this particular view. I am able to insert the records to the view but not able to delete from view. Could you please point me an error in this below piece of SQL statements?

```
create view v1 as
select a.* 
from appearance a, photo p, photographer u, person s
where a.isShownIn = p.id
and p.takenBy = u.id
and u.id = s.id
and s.name = 'Fred';

create user 'Fred';

grant insert, delete on assignment_5.v1 to 'Fred';


delete from v1 where v1.shows = 17;`
```

The appearance table has shows and isShownIn columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL documentation states:

> "For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship
>   between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table."

MySQL is performing as-designed, and is preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot here.  Essentially, the number of rows that would be deleted from your view does not match the number of rows that would be deleted from the underlying tables.  Also, do you want to delete the photo, appearance, person or the photographer?  Or all of them?  Or just some of them?  MySQL doesn't know for sure either, so it doesn't allow the operation.

Bearing that in-mind, run this query:

```
SELECT IS_UPDATABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'v1';
```

If the result is anything other than "YES", then you might want to consider redesigning your view.  The other option, would be to delete from the underlying tables directly.

Also it's a good idea for an updatable view to created using the "WITH CHECK OPTION" clause.  This prevents UPDATEs or INSERTs to underlying tables, except those which meet the conditions defined in the view's WHERE clause.  Or in your case, prevent Fred from messing with Bob's photos.

Comment: Even my view is updatable, i'm getting the same error!
SELECT IS_UPDATABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'v_option_batch'; Result is YES.
I can update the view, but cannot delete from it.