# Delete rows from join view table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have 45K rows in table (out of 125k)that i need to delete.

```
 DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE `name` IS NULL ;
```

returned

```
ERROR 1395 (HY000): Can not delete from join view
```

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286894/mysql-error-1395-can-not-delete-from-join-view

Comment: It's a join view, so MySQL doesn't know which of the underlying tables you're wanting to delete from.

Comment: so how do i remove all rows that has 'name" null?

Comment: @karthikr its related, but no real answer there

Comment: Can you show me the SQL to create the view?

Comment: hmm h?ow do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

do a `SHOW CREATE VIEW tablename` to see which tables are in the `select` of the join view. the result will be something like :

```
CREATE VIEW tablename AS SELECT name, f2, f3 … FROM table1;
```

when you have the name of the table that have a column called `name` (`table1`), you can do your delete:

```
DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE `name` IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE `name`="" ;
```